# Django common code in views

Tags: django, django-views

I have been reading around for other answers but i am still not understanding what is the quickest and best way to using common code for multiple views.

Let's say i have this code, that reflects a user's points, that i want displayed in many of the views.

```
if(request.user.is_authenticated()):
    # UserLove
    userLove = 0
    ul = Love.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
    for u in ul:
        userLove += u.amount
else:
    userLove= 0
```

I saw words about using decorators. I heard about generic views and subclassed views, and someone also mentioned `context processors`

Can you tell me which is best, and how would my code look if I had View1 and View2 as examples. Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I agree that either Decorators or Template Tags are the best approach here. Decorators are applied to the *function* (i.e. view), so for instance if you wanted to make sure that a user was logged in before they accessed a view, you could use a Decorator. But not for determining values *inside* the function.

If you have a block of code that you want to re-use in several places, just make it a separate *function*, maybe in a *utilities* file, then import the function. For instance:

```
# myapps.utilities.py
from models import Love
def computeLove(request):
    # code for determining value here
    return LoveValue

# someView.py
from myapps.utilities import computeLove

def showRatings(request):
    lv = computeLove(request)
```

It's a standard programming method, you don't really need any specific Django features for this.

Comment: This is how i did it and it works good. however, what bothers me is this `Prior to Django 1.3, generic views were implemented as functions. The function-based implementation has been deprecated in favor of the class-based approach described here.` from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: @mgPePe, there are two different things involved here - a *view*, and a *common block of code*. A view is just a function that takes a request object, and returns an HTTP response of some kind. Whether it's implemented as a free-standing function, or part of a class, is unrelated to how a *common block of code* is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, probably you need something else, but in your case you can do this thing using template tag, for example:

in appname/util.py you have to write the part of code which will return data you need.
then in template tag you do something like

```
# appname_tags.py
from django import template
from appname.util import get_rating

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def user_rating(user):
    rating = get_rating(user)
    return rating if rating is not None else ''
```

so in your template file:

```
{% load appname_tags %}

{% user_rating anyuser %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, writing either a [Template Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) or a [Template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) is the best approach.